# The fresh layout resource file not loading after the device orientation change

Tags: java, android, layout, orientation, screen-orientation

I have created an app which has a help screen which is initiated by a 3 dots help menu button on the action bar.The help screen has the following layout xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="280dp"
    android:layout_height="380dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/aboutus_new"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="0dp">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@color/mehendi"
        android:minHeight="40dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        app:title="Info">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/closeButtn"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
            android:background="@drawable/circlebackground"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="X"
            android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>


    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayoutnew"
        android:layout_width="350dp"
        android:layout_height="232dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageViewnew"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:foregroundGravity="center_horizontal"
            android:src="@drawable/eat_icon"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline25"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewnew"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:text="@string/aboutus"
            android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
            android:textSize="13sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/imageView6"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/imageView6"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView6" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="280dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
            android:foregroundGravity="center_horizontal"
            android:gravity="center"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/guideline24"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/textView">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="269dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                android:text="@string/introduc"
                android:textAlignment="textStart"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                android:textSize="13sp"
                android:textStyle="bold|italic"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <android.support.constraint.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/guideline24"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.0" />

        <android.support.constraint.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/guideline25"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="1" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="1dp">


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageViewfre"
            android:layout_width="55dp"
            android:layout_height="55dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
            android:background="@drawable/mason"
            android:baselineAlignBottom="true"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imageView2"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread_inside"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.6" />


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="55dp"
            android:layout_height="55dp"
            android:background="@drawable/app"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imageView4"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.6" />


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_width="55dp"
            android:layout_height="55dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
            android:background="@drawable/creations"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView4"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView4"
            android:layout_width="55dp"
            android:layout_height="55dp"
            android:background="@drawable/swrd"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imageView3"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView2"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

The above layout has also an alternative layout for the landscape mode in 'aboutus-land' folder.The above layout gets loaded on pressing 3 dotted button and while it is still active, if I changes the device's rotation this still reloads instead of its landscape alternative. But when I closes it manually by pressing close button and after closing ,if I changes device's rotation and then opens it again using 3 dotted menu button.The altenative landscape layout gets loaded. Why it's happening? anyone with any suggestion please help me out.

Comment: instead of using 'aboutus-land' for landscape modes, try using `ViewModel` which handles the config-changes without having to create another layout.

Comment: but all other layouts are loading except this,what do you think about this problem.The only difference is that all other layouts have corresponding activity file except aboutus screen layout

Answer (score -1):

If you want your Activity to handle configuration changes, you should declare it in your AndroidManifest.xml like this:

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity"
          android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize">
```

Please refer here for more info: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes#HandlingTheChange